# Miscellaneous Files when creating a windows form

Tags: winforms

When I create a new windows form project i can't do anything inside of it: [Miscellaneous Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFqYA.png)

I try to create a new project but I stumble again with the same problem.
All the files are in the default repo folder so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: See: [Create a Windows Forms app in Visual Studio with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-csharp-winform-visual-studio) and [Tutorial: Create a Windows Forms app with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/get-started/create-app-visual-studio).

Comment: Code is not in the question but attached as a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the **Visual Studio Installer**  and then choose **Modify** and then find the **.NET Desktop Development Workload** install the workload which will prompt you to close all active visual studio windows so the download process can start and then afterwards Visual Studio should be able to recognize your windows forms projects.

These workloads are very important and for you to be ale to create a project based on any programming language such as C++ or C# then the **Desktop Development Workload** associated with the language needs to be installed from the **Visual Studio Installer**. You can find the **Installer** from the **Windows Start Menu** and it's usually located close to the Visual Studio launch icon on the start menu.